# Else não funciona no PHP

Tags: php, if, else

Estou tentando utilizar o código abaixo, mas o `else` não funciona. Retorna o erro `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)`

```
<?php if ($status == 'True') ?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <img src="'.$poster.'" class="poster">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9">
    <div class="imdb-panel">
        <div class="imdb-head">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="imdb-body">
            <p style="margin: 0">Nome: <?php echo $title ?></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin: 0">Data de lançamento: <?php echo $released ?></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin: 0">Dirigido por: <?php echo $director ?></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin: 0">Escrito por: <? echo $writer ?></p>
            <br>
            <p style="margin: 0">Elenco principal: <?php echo $actors ?></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="imdb-panel">
        <div class="imdb-head">
            Título não encontrado
        </div>
        <div class="imdb-body">
            <p style="text-align: center;">O título que você procurou não pode ser encontrado.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou o `:` na primeira linha:

```
<?php if ($status == 'True'): ?>
----------------------------^
```

E `;` no final:

```
<?php endif; ?>
-----------^
```

Na terceira linha, tem algo que não faz sentido:

```
<img src="'.$poster.'" class="poster">
-----------^^^^^^^^^
```

Você estaria concatenando uma variável PHP dentro do HTML? Substitua por `echo`:

```
<img src="<?php echo $poster; ?>" class="poster">
```